# Power supply over-current protection mode: constant current

Tags: power-supply

I am researching power supply over-current protection modes, and I have a question about constant current.

Wikipedia claims (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foldback_(power_supply_design)) that the current remains constant while the voltage goes to zero. Doesn't this violate Ohm's Law? R is not changing, I is not changing, but somehow the voltage can change willy nilly?

What gives?

Comment: If R and I don't change, V doesn't change too.

Comment: Even if it's a switching or linear regulator, there are two main regulation modes: constant voltage or constant current. And they are ORed in feedback circuit. So, if one (constant voltage) fails (by a short or overload) the other (constant current) will take control. Thus, in constant current mode, you shouldn't expect constant voltage.

Comment: R *is* changing, and Ohm's law tells you that for a constant current and decreasing R the voltage decreases with R. When R approaches 0, so does V.

Comment: I see, I guess I misunderstood the part where the graph defines the behavior as the load changes. That should have been obvious. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your power supply to constant current mode, the voltage will change depending on the load. Pure Ohms law V = IR. If I is constant and you change R, V must change.

Obviously within the limits of how much V is available.

So when you set your current limit on the supply and watch the meters while you increase the load, at first V will be constant and the current needle will ramp up to the limit. After that the current needle will stay put and the voltage needle will drop.