# Why is the current control knob in DC voltage source kept at maximum initially?

Tags: power-supply

In a DC Voltage Source(0-15-30V), why do we need to keep the current control knob at maximum at the beginning?

Note : I am using this DC Voltage Source for basic experiments of electronics like getting characteristics of P-N junction diode, zener diode, etc. This advice came from my instructor in the course 'Electronic Devices and Circuits Laboratory' and is also mentioned in the laboratory manual.

[image: Laboratory manual page]

Comment: You have read some advice which is specific to some particular use case or equipment, not a general principle. Please quote and/or link to it so we can understand the context.

Comment: SIgh I know I answered this question before somewhere...

Comment: @Trevor I could not find any other question and nothing relevant came up on a Google search

Comment: @KevinReid I updated it

Comment: This seems to be specific to a certain instrument. I sure don't do this on any supply. Only thing that can happen on some is if you set their current right down they limit their voltage with no-load connected due to the current drawn by the sense circuit.

Comment: Keeping the current control to the maximum also seems to defeat the purpose - you would use it to limit current in event of a circuit failiure. If you have a issue in your circuit, you are going to have long killed it before you can lower that current down with the controls.

Comment: Your edit explains what you are doing but does not say _where you got this advice_. Please quote and/or link to where you read the claim that the current knob should be turned up.

Comment: Yes @akshayk07, was not a sigh at you.. it's just almost impossible to search your own answers easily on here and I can't find it.

Comment: I usually do the opposite and set the current limit to the minimum I can consistent with operating whatever it is powering.  This will help protect the device if there is a problem.

Comment: @KevinReid Updated it, now with an image of the source.

Comment: @Trevor, go to your user page and the search box will be pre-filled with a term to restrict searches to your posts. But yes, searching for terms like "current" is not much use; you'd have to remember some unique term that was used in the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @ThePhoton thanks.. my issue is the "remember" part LOL Good to know though.

Comment: @Trevor, Is [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/293617/6334) what you were thinking of?

Comment: Or [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323119/6334) where the question is even closer to this one?

Comment: @ThePhoton ah right... the second one. I knew it was familiar. Thanks

Comment: OP, [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/323114/6334) seems to be closely related to yours.

Comment: @ThePhoton Both of them didn't have the words 'current control knob' in their title, or I would have found them. Thanks for pointing them out though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diode characteristic measurement - initial tester settings](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/323114/diode-characteristic-measurement-initial-tester-settings)

Comment: @winny That was mentioned earlier and it could not be found because the title was pretty different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice when initially setting up a bench supplies is to set the voltage first with no load.

Since the current limiter will hold the voltage at a lower level if set too low, it is prudent to turn it all the way up initially to make sure that the voltage indicated is indeed the regulated voltage not the limited voltage. Once the voltage is set it is then prudent to wind back the current limit to a level you expect not to exceed with the load you are about to attach.

If you do it the other way around with a load attached the voltage you see may in fact be the limited voltage. If the load current drops it can cause the output voltage to suddenly rise to the higher set-voltage level and may damage your load.

Generally when powering an unknown load or circuit of unknown quality, it is prudent to start at zero volts, wind the current limit to max, then slowly increase the voltage while monitoring the current meter manually. If you see the current increase too rapidly, back off the voltage and try and figure out the cause.

Comment: This is the likely rational but it is risky. Setting the current to some LOW value above zero would be less risky and what I do in practice and have seen others do.  Set the voltage, then short the output to set the current limit if known.  Otherwise set the voltage with circuit attached and then back off the current limit until the voltage drops (or limit is indicated with LED on PSU) and then turn current limit up a bit.  This protects you from over current.